How to create an Artisan command which does not throw errors when options passed to it are not defined in its signature?
I want to create a command with options not defined in its signature (I directly pass the options to another command inside mine).
Currently, when I run my command without having its signature precisely defined, it throws an error:
The "--my-option-not-defined-in-signatue" option does not exist. 

Is there a way to disable this check?

What would the purpose of this be?

I call another command which have a shit ton of arguments and does not sanitize them php artisan test

In the command constructor, you can disable those checks by using the method ignoreValidationErrors(), like so:
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->ignoreValidationErrors();
}

